# JSON+Ajax append and create a dynamic Div

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to create an html page that most of its parts are currently static and are loaded from JSON files.

I am trying to create some "posts" and attach "comments" to them. currently I have two JSON files: posts.JSON and comments.JSON.

posts.JSON contains the following:

```
[{"Name":"Liza","Date":"December 22 2016","Content":"What a nice profile.","Id":"1"},
{"Name":"Tom","Date":"December 23 2016","Content":"Good luck in your new job.","Id":"2"}]
```

comments.JSON cointains the following:

```
[{"Name":"Bob Jacobs","Comment":"How nice of you to say","Id":"1"},
{"Name":"Rob Sherman","Comment":"Indeed a nice profile!","Id":"1"},
{"Name":"Roni James","Comment":"You couldn't of wished him something better :-)","Id":"2"}]
```

What I am trying to do is to match comments to their posts while creating a div for the post by matching the comment Id to the post Id(if they are the same its a match) but I am unable to do it cause I miss a way to define the sub div class name and therefore unable to set it properly(currently its set o just '2' which is one of the id's) I also don't know how eliminate a situation that a comment with id-'2' wont get attached to a post with id-'1'.

Here is some of the HTML code that is involved:

```
<div class="row" id="middle">
          <div class="col-sm-8" id="left">
               <div class="forPosts"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4" id="right">
               <p class="myText">Jobs that may intest you:</p>
               <div class="forPosition"></div>
          </div>
      </div>




    <!--Footer-->
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
      <p  class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"> &nbsp;Created by Sorokina E. 333815611 and Menaker T. 201096690 </p>
    </footer>

    <!--My JS for tooltip-->
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $.getJSON("../files/posts.json",function(result){
          $.each(result, function (index, value) {
            $(".forPosts").append("<div class=\"divStyle2\"><span class=\"myText2\">Posted by " +value.Name +" - "+value.Date+"</span><br><div class=\"divStyle\">"+value.Content+"</div><br><button class=\"myButton\">Like</button>&nbsp &nbsp<button class=\"myButton\">Comment</button>&nbsp &nbsp<button class=\"myButton\">Show/hide comment</button></div><div class='2'></div><br>");
          });
        });

        $.getJSON("../files/comments.json",function(result){
            $.each(result, function (index, value) {
              var $x = document.getElementsByClassName(""+value.id);
              if($x==value.id){
              $("."+x).append("<div class=\"divStyle2\"><span class=\"myText3\">" +value.Name +" : "+value.Comment+"</span><br></div>");}
            });
          });
});
```

Thanks for any help,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

what i would suggest to do is try to place the comment for each post in the post oject, ex :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Liza",
        "date": "December 22 2016",
        "content": "What a nice profile.",
        "comments": [
            {
                "name": "Bob Jacobs",
                "Comment": "How nice of you to say"
            },
            {
                "name": "Rob Sherman",
                "comment": "Indeed a nice profile!"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    // other post
    }
]
```

this way, you can simply loop in your comments each time you create a post using a simple jquery loop. ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var post = {} // Here goes your JSON.parse of yours post object
    $.each(post, function($postIndex, $post){
        $(".forPosts").append("<div class=\"divStyle2\"><span class=\"myText2\">Posted by " +$post.Name +" - "+$post.Date+"</span><br><div class=\"divStyle\">"+$post.Content+"</div><br><button class=\"myButton\">Like</button>&nbsp &nbsp<div class=\"comments\"></div>");
        $.each($post.comments, function($commentIndex, $comment) {
                $(".forPosts").children().last().find(".comments").append("<button class=\"myButton\">Comment</button>&nbsp &nbsp<button class=\"myButton\">Show/hide comment</button></div><div class='2'></div><br>");
        });
    });
});
```

This should work, i have not tested it, so there might have a few syntax error but basicly i'm looping in your post and then in your comments adding each comment to the last children of `$('.forPost')` added which is the lst post we added in the previous loop.
Hopes this helps !

- Nic